# WIN32OLE.attach is an undefined method when trying to attach HTTPWatch with Watir to work in IE9

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer-9, watir, httpwatch

I've been trying to get HTTPWatch work with Watir automation in IE9.

I searched these sites which provide the code:

[Link1](http://apihelp.httpwatch.com/#Ruby%20-%20Driving%20the%20browser%20with%20Watir.html)

So I basically copied their piece and wrote this piece of code just to test the attach method:

```
**require 'rubygems'
require 'win32ole'
require 'watir'
ct = WIN32OLE.new('HttpWatch.Controller')
ie = Watir::IE.new
httpw = ct.Attach(ie.ie)**
```

and I got the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `attach' for WIN32OLE:Class

**My Ruby is 1.8.7, Watir is 2.0.1, HTTPWatch is 8.1, IE 9**. I have to use those versions as defined by the team.

I've been searching on google for hours, I found that attach is not a listed method in WIN32OLE here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/

So I wonder how would I be able to use HTTPWatch to record time spent by Watir automation in IE9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
httpw = ct.IE.Attach(ie.ie)
```

Note: This is based on what I saw in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980888/how-to-get-win32ole-handle-for-ie-via-watir-webdriver) regarding getting HTTPWatch with Watir-Webdriver (instead of original Watir). I do not have HTTPWatch, so I have not tested it.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer. Thanks! Even though I would really like to know the reason behind.

Comment: And  just registered so I can't give you an up. Sorry about that.

Comment: HTTPWatch supports both IE and Firefox. The syntax is basically saying for my HTTPWatch object, use the IE methods to attach to a certain browser. This is opposed to someone who wants a Firefox browser. This might be a help [overview of working with HTTPWatch](http://apihelp.httpwatch.com/#Ruby%20-%20Overview.html).